# Can install gem ruby-debug, but rails server can't find it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems, ruby-debug

I found a pretty interesting problem installing ruby gems

```
bluehat@Matapan:~/code/Amacron$ rails server --debugger
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
You need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode. With gems, use 'gem install ruby-debug'
Exiting
bluehat@Matapan:~/code/Amacron$ sudo gem install ruby-debug
Successfully installed ruby-debug-0.10.4
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for ruby-debug-0.10.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for ruby-debug-0.10.4...
bluehat@Matapan:~/code/Amacron$ rails server --debugger
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
You need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode. With gems, use 'gem install ruby-debug'
Exiting
bluehat@Matapan:~/code/Amacron$ sudo gem update ruby-debug
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
bluehat@Matapan:~/code/Amacron$ gem --version
1.3.7
bluehat@Matapan:~/code/Amacron$ rails --version
Rails 3.0.3
```

System is an up-to-date Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you put this gem in your application's Gemfile?

Comment: It was commented out. That was extraordinarily humiliating. Thank you good sir.

Comment: @Katy: Happens to the best of us. Glad I helped :)

Comment: Worked for me too. Frustrating that the error message's advice doesn't work!

Comment: @Katy: well you're in (possibly good?) company ... I wound up here after Googling for exactly the same problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by installing the irb package. The error message was about ruby-debug, but once I installed the debian packed for irb all was fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. The reason was that in the application's Gemfile, the line "gem 'ruby-debug'" was commented out. I enabled this line and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. I tried running script/server as sudo, and that worked fine, and oddly after that I was able to run it as my regular user.